# Java Image Processing

Tags: java, swing

I want to load an image in a jframe in swing based gui. then want to edit that image like setting contrast or brightness. after editing the changes should be saved to the original image.

Please show me How to do this? show me any one change like brightness or contrast or any other change...

Comment: Start from here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html

Comment: *"I want.."* ..you to write my code.  My time is too valuable to devote to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good book on the subject - [Filthy Rich Clients](http://filthyrichclients.org/). Read about [image filters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html). In particular check out [RescaleOp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/RescaleOp.html). Here is a [sample](http://exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt.image/Bright.html) that updates image brightness.